# Match pattern and then replace using the pattern

Tags: vim

I would like to find a good way in Vim to do this search and replace for the following -

```
name_1
end
name_2
end

name_3
end
```

where I take name_"x" and append it to it's following "end" statement. So it would look like this -

```
name_1
end_name_1
name_2
end_name_2
name_3

end_name_3
```

Note - the empty line before name_3 ruins a constant line spacing between "name_x" and "end". So I was thinking of something like

```
:g/\(name_x\)/,/end/ s/end/end_\1/
```

Now that doesn't work trying to store the first pattern like that but hopefully you get the idea. Any tricks here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is that `\1` refers to the current substitution's match group not the `:g` command's pattern. Sadly you can not access previous match groups from previous searches.  There are however ways to accomplish your goal. The first I would suggest is a macro.

First off start on a a non matching line. This can be done by inserting a blank line at the top of the file if needed (just remove it afterwards).

1. start the macro search for your pattern: `/name_\d\+`
2. yank until the end of your pattern: `y//e`
3. find the end pattern: `/end/e`
4. insert a underscore `a_`
5. paste with `p`
6. end your macro `q`
7. execute the macro with a large number. e.g. `999@q`

Here is the macro I used:

```
:let @q = "/name_\\d\\+\<cr>y//e\<cr>/end/e\<cr>a_\<esc>p"
```

The other way is to use the `:global` command in a similar fashion to your attempt.

```
:g/name_\d\+/let @@=matchstr(getline('.'),'name_\d\+')|/end/s//\=submatch(0).'_'.@@/
```

I personally this is much too complicated, but it is nice to have options. The command can be broken down into the following parts:

- `:g/name_\d\+` execute a command on each line matching name_ and some number
- `getline('.')` will return a string of the current line
- `matchstr(getline('.'), 'name_\d\+')` will return only the matching part of the current line
- `let @@ = matchstr(...)` will set the matched portion to the default register
- `/end/s/` will execute a `:s` on the following line that matches `end`
- `s//\=.../` matches the last used pattern and replaces it with an express.
- `submatch(0).'_'.@@` create a string with the whole matched pattern followed by an underscore and the contents of the unnamed register.

For more information on the following topics see:

```
:h q
:h search-offset
:h :g
:h :let-@
:h registers
:h matchstr(
:h getline(
:h range
:h submatch(
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This was very helpful. I always tend to use global command subs before macros, which for this case a macro definitely seems the way to go. But I'll be studying the command breakdown you gave as well.

Comment: Peter uses both `:global` and a macro: `:g` is used to define the lines on which to act and the macro is used to do the action. `:global` and macros are meant for each other.

Comment: Romainl you are correct they are very handy together. I personally prefer `:g` coupled with `:norm`, but the idea is quite similar. Maybe I should add the following solution: `g/name_\d\+/norm y/name_\d\+/e^M/end/e^Ma_^]p`. Thoughts? I do feel however that I might be making an assumption that lines start without any leading white space.

Answer (score 0):

A regex based solution is:

```
:%s/\(name.*\)\(\n\+.*\)/\1\2_\1
```

This group every line which contains `name` followed by anything, another group which could have any number of `return` followed bay anything, then append first group to the second one.